# Google Playstore publishing different project with same key?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, publishing

I am fairly new to Android Studio and Google Playstore publishing. I have a project made in Unity, already published to the app store. If I want to update the app by remaking the project in Android Studio, can I use the same key I used before? 
By using the same key, will it show up as just an update? 
Does switching from Unity to Android Studio create any major publishing problems?

Any advice will help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the same key for signing your native Android app and upload the apk to same project on play store. It will show up as an update without creating any publishing problems as files for all apps are converted into .dex format during apk build independent of the tech stack used.